# why is visual studio 2012 slow?

Tags: xaml, compiler-construction, crash, visual-studio-2012

I'm frustrated to develop xaml application in visual studio 2012. Why does it always freeze, even crash? I know it has to generate some files when you edit the xaml file. Is there any method or configuration to make it running fluently? And the compiler's speed for C++/CX is toooooo slow. I hardly put up with that. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't had any problems so far. I have felt that its more responsive than 2010 anyway. Ensure that you have the minimum hardware requirements.

Comment: Our developers also having the same problem when editing the xaml. You will notice when you edit the Xaml file there will be a XDesProc.exe running and that caused the hang.  If you killed that XDesProc process, the hang will gone.  The way to fix it is to switch your xaml editor to not using the default ones.

Comment: In the XAML designer, there is an option called Turn on/off rendering of Effects, the icon is (Fx), when I Turned off that option the XAML designer comes faster like vs2010 again :)